# Classes, Objects, and Methods help in Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

NetBeans won't let me run my program because of a problem regarding the public class HotelManagement and the public class Room. Can anyone help me fix this problem so my program will run smoothly. Thanks

```
public class HotelManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room room1 = new Room(3348, 80, "Single Bed"); 
        Room room2 = new Room(3347, 90, "Double Bed"); 
        Room room3 = new Room(3346, 140, "Suite");
        room1.Book(); 
        room2.printRoomInfo(); 
        room3.setRate(180); 
        room1.Release(); 
        room1.printRoomInfo(); 
        room3.printRoomInfo();
    }

    }



    public class Room {


    private final int number;
    private final String type;
    private int rate;
    private boolean isBooked;


    public Room(int number, int rate, String type) {

        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.isBooked = false; 
    }


    public void Book() {
        System.out.println("Room " + this.number + " has successfully been booked.");
        this.isBooked = true;
    } 

    // This method "releases" the booking on the room by setting the instance variable isBooked to false
    public void Release() {
        System.out.println("Room " + this.number + " has successfully been released.");
        this.isBooked = false;
    }

    // Print basic info about the current Room objects state 
    public void printRoomInfo() {
        String state; 
        if (this.isBooked == true) { 
            state = "Unavailable"; 
        }

        else { 
            state = "Available";
        }

        System.out.println("Room " + this.number + " is a " + this.type + ". Rate is: " + this.rate + "$ per night. " + state + ".");

    }


    public void setRate(int newRate) {
        this.rate = newRate;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your program run fine for me, did you put all the code in one single file ?

Comment: Yup, it's one top level class per file.

Comment: @RobertMoskal You can have only one 'public' class in a file. So you should either make all the classes other than 'HotelManagement' non-public or follow the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put both classes into one file you need:

1. move Room class declaration inside HotelManagement class
2. make it static, like `public static class Room {`

so, final structure will be like this:

```
public class HotelManagement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
...
    }

    public static class Room {
....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only **one public class in .java file** which will be the class that has your public static void main. Other classes if in same file cannot be public.

```
public class HotelManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room room1 = new Room(3348, 80, "Single Bed"); 
        Room room2 = new Room(3347, 90, "Double Bed"); 
        Room room3 = new Room(3346, 140, "Suite");
        room1.Book(); 
        room2.printRoomInfo(); 
        room3.setRate(180); 
        room1.Release(); 
        room1.printRoomInfo(); 
        room3.printRoomInfo();
    }

    }



     class Room {


    private final int number;
    private final String type;
    private int rate;
    private boolean isBooked;


    public Room(int number, int rate, String type) {

        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.isBooked = false; 
    }


    public void Book() {
        System.out.println("Room " + this.number + " has successfully been booked.");
        this.isBooked = true;
    } 

    // This method "releases" the booking on the room by setting the instance variable isBooked to false
    public void Release() {
        System.out.println("Room " + this.number + " has successfully been released.");
        this.isBooked = false;
    }

    // Print basic info about the current Room objects state 
    public void printRoomInfo() {
        String state; 
        if (this.isBooked == true) { 
            state = "Unavailable"; 
        }

        else { 
            state = "Available";
        }

        System.out.println("Room " + this.number + " is a " + this.type + ". Rate is: " + this.rate + "$ per night. " + state + ".");

    }


    public void setRate(int newRate) {
        this.rate = newRate;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one public class per source file. So to make your code work, you need to do one of the things

1. Put each public class in a separate source file. Public classes can be accessed from anywhere regardless the package.
2. Remove `public` access modifier for the class `Room`

The other way is to make the class `Room` static and put it inside the class `HotelManagement`. But I recommend you to learn about advanced concepts like static nested classes and inner classes in Java when you're very good at basic concepts.